# Later you fell down your teeth will gone

Tags: grammar

He was eating lollipop with standing.

> "Please sit down. ***Later* you fell down your teeth will gone.**"

Mostly we say, Your teeth will gone if you fell down.

Can I rephrase it as the highlighted sentence?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the context.  Are you worried he will break his teeth on the lollipop?  Does that really happen?  I think teeth are much harder than even hard candy.

Comment: _He was eating lollipop while standing. She said, "Please sit down. If you fall, you might break your teeth."_

Comment: @Andrew, I have seen it happen with a kid and a water bottle. Though what actually happens is that front (milk) teeth get knocked out, not broken. So "If you fall over, you will knock your teeth out.."

Comment: @JavaLatte  I can understand falling over, hitting an object against the ground, and knocking out some baby teeth.  I don't understand the connection here between the lollipop and falling down.  Is the child's balance so precarious that any distraction could cause him to fall over?

Comment: This question is difficult to understand.  Please try to answer the questions in the comments section.  In order to write good answers, we need to understand what you're trying to express.

Comment: BradC has listed the answer that clearly describe what I want to express. You're going to fall and knock your teeth out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Please sit down. Later you fell down your teeth will gone."

This is very ungrammatical. "**If you fell, your teeth would *be* gone**" is slightly better, but probably still not how a native speaker would say it. A few other options:

- **Please sit down. You're going to fall and knock your teeth out.**
- **Please sit down. If you fell down, you could knock your teeth out.**
- **Please sit down. I don't have time for a trip to the dentist today.**
- **Please sit down. You could fall and break your teeth.**

Answer (score -1):

`If you fell down you will break your teeth so please sit down`. To highlight the second sentence we can say it first. It is good practice to use teeth will break instead of teeth will gone.

Comment: "If you **fall** down you will break your teeth..." or "If you **fell** down you **would** break your teeth..."

Comment: ya sorry. that's my mistake @JavaLatte